# XAML / WPF simple colour animation

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard, blend

I am trying to replicate this colour animation based on the MouseEnter/MouseLeave trigger - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4kih1BSRYxY

I created a Storyboard using Blend, however I couldn't find the best (correct!) control/effect to use, so I created it using multi-Canvas within a grid. As you can see it's nowhere near as smooth as the video. What am I doing wrong? Should I tweak the timings, or is there another control I should be using? Can I use the expander for this type of thing?

I want to achieve this using pure XAML, no code behind.

```
<Window x:Class="ColourAnimation.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="MenuAnimation">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas1">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas2">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas3">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas4">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas5">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas6">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas7">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas8">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas9">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas10">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas11">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas12">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>


    <Storyboard x:Key="MenuAnimation2">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas13">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas14">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas15">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.1" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas16">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas17">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas18">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas19">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.3" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas20">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas21">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas22">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas23">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas24">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas25">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>





    <Storyboard x:Key="MenuAnimationReversed">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas1">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas2">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas3">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas4">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas5">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas6">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas7">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas8">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas9">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas10">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas11">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas12">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Red"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>

    <Storyboard x:Key="MenuAnimationReversed2">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas13">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Green"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas14">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas15">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.0" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas16">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas17">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.8" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas18">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas19">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.6" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas20">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas21">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas22">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas23">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas24">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="canvas25">
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.0" Value="Green"/>
            <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="White"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>


</Window.Resources>

<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger 
        SourceName="btnCraig"
        RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuAnimation}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger 
        SourceName="btnCraig"
        RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuAnimationReversed}"/>
    </EventTrigger>

    <EventTrigger 
        SourceName="btnCraig2"
        RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuAnimation2}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
    <EventTrigger 
        SourceName="btnCraig2"
        RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MenuAnimationReversed2}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>


<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="10,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="12,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="14,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="16,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="18,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="20,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas6" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="22,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas7" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="24,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas8" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="26,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas9" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="28,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="30,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="32,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="34,72,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnCraig" Content="Button1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="68" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"/>

    <Canvas x:Name="canvas13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="10,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas14" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="12,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="14,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="16,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas17" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="18,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas18" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="20,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas19" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="22,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="24,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas21" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="26,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="28,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="30,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas24" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="32,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="34,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="5" Background="White"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnCraig2" Content="Button2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="59" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent"/>


</Grid>
```

Comment: That's not at all how I would approach this. I'll write something for you.

Comment: Whoa ya you can do that effect with a fraction of what you got going on here and make it highly re-usable in something like a `Button` style template. Adding a comment to follow along and see Andy's result he's kindly volunteered.

Comment: Thanks Andy and Chris - looking forward to it. Feel free to point me in the right direction, more than happy to try it myself - or am I way off? Like I said, I am very new to this so just trying it out. Thanks again, really appreciate it. Craig

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay - I thought I posted this earlier.

My mainwindow markup

```
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox Name="ViewSelect"
             ItemsSource="{Binding ViewChoices}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewChoice, Mode=TwoWay}"
             >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Brush}">
                        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".1" ScaleY="1"/>
                        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>

                        <Rectangle.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="True">
                                        <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation  
                                                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                                      From="0.1" To=".9" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                        <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation 
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.RenderTransform).(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"
                                                                   From="0.9" To=".1" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Rectangle.Style>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Background="Transparent"
                            Command="{Binding ChoiceCommand}"
                            BorderThickness="0"
                               />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Notice that I'm templating data into a listboxitem which has a rectangle and button in it. The buttons do nothing in my code here because I've not set up any commands for them. But they are ready to do so...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace wpf_AnimatedMenu
{
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<ViewChoice> ViewChoices { get; set; }
    = new ObservableCollection<ViewChoice>
    {
        new ViewChoice{ Name="Page One", Brush=Brushes.Green},
         new ViewChoice{ Name="Page Two", Brush=Brushes.Yellow},
    };

    private ViewChoice selectedViewChoice;

    public ViewChoice SelectedViewChoice
    {
        get { return selectedViewChoice; }
        set { selectedViewChoice = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

and ViewChoice.

```
public class ViewChoice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }
    public ICommand ChoiceCommand { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the zipped solution on onedrive:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AmPvL3r385Qhgph8xc90FzTq8hrWQQ

Comment: Thanks Andy - really appreciate your time. Is your VM missing some code?

Comment: I've added the link. Only thing missing is using statements.